# Don't want to show the option menu in all pages

Tags: android

I don't want to show the option menu in all pages when the menu button click. I want to specify the page to display option menu. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can override the below method to disable/enable menu options as per your need...

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```